# Apps that were open when I restart still open on startup even though I disabled that?

Tags: macos, imac, startup, restart

I'm on an iMac mid-2010 with OS X Mountain Lion.

I disabled the feature that reopens windows the next time I startup my computer after a restart, but for some reason the windows that I had open when I shut down still open on startup.

**How do I stop this from happening for good?**

Comment: What did you do to disable the feature that reopens windows? There are two different features: one that reopens *windows* when you restart a *program* and the other that reopens *programs* when you restart your *computer*.

Comment: I'm talking about the one that appears when you click on the Apple icon and select "Restart...". I unchecked the box there.